# Resampling in a particle filter with replacement

Tags: particle-filter

Please help. The condensation algorithm steps to track an object in a frame are:

1. Initialize a point and choose N random points around it and set the weight to be 1/N.
2. Propagate the points as per the dynamic model (constant velocity model).
3. Now, calculate the weights of each particle using an observation model. Till now, there are N particles.
4. Now, in the resampling step pick N particles from the above set of particles?

What? How can we pick N particles from N particles?

Comment: there are many particle resampling techniques: multinomial, deterministic and residual. Nando de Freitas has an implementation of a particle filter for switching linear dynamic system that includes the above resampling algorithms: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nando/software.html

Answer (score 3):

How can we pick N particles from N particles?

Pick N particles with replacement, i.e one particle can be chosen more than one time according to the weight you assign to it.

If you have 3 particles , with weight [0.1 0.2 0.7 ] , then choose the 3rd particle twice and 2nd particle one,hence you have selected get 3 particles from 3 particles itself.

There are many techniques to do this step i.e resampling N particles.Even I am trying to write a code for this part only.

Some sites where you can learn about resampling is :-

- Udacity - Artificial Intelligence for Robotics - [Link to the course page](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs373/unit-3#resampling)
- IEEE paper- tutorial on Particle filter for online .... by Arulampalam ,gordon maskell, This is a highly cited paper,and almost every where people have taken references for particle filter from here only.
- This paper is lecture tutorial in which they have explained resampling nicely, just follow the algorithm, and i think your code will do the resampling [Link](http://www.ces.clemson.edu/~ahoover/ece854/lecture-notes/lecture-pf.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how much detail is required...forgive me if most of this is known. The particle filter attempts to estimate the posterior distribution p(x_t|y_1,...,y_t) based on the observations y_1,...,y_t. The "correction step" relies on the simplification:

```
p(x_t|y_1,...,y_t) = p(y_t|x_t)p(x_t|y_1,...,y_t-1)/p(y_t|y_1,...,y_t-1)
```

N points are sampled from this posterior distribution, then evolved according to the right-hand side to approximate the next posterior. We are not dealing with normals so we need to approximate more than just 2 moments. The N points for the next step are then resampled from the new posterior, rather than just using the old points, wherever they have eveolved. The reason is the well-known degeneracy effect - that all points but 1 will tend to 0.

So we are not picking N particles from N particles, but rather throwing away the old particles, and resampling N from the new estimate of the posterior.